# Why does my background video play after alert?

Tags: javascript, video, background, alert

Currently, my background video will only play after user would press "okay" in the alert pop-up. How can I create the code to have the background video play as soon as the window appears, or the page loads, rather than having to press ok from the alert. **The background video needs to play before the alerts appear.** I am new to javascript, so I need code examples, or edits to my current code to properly understand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>

function myText() {
    var txt;
    var person = prompt("What's your name?", "");
    if (person == null || person == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

function playAlert(msg, wav) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var audio = new Audio(wav);
        audio.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {
            audio.play();
            alert(msg);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("video");
    };

playAlert("Thank you.", 'Images/thankyou.wav?.wav?.wav?.wav?.wav')
.then(function() {
    return playAlert("Sorry, I haven't introduced myself.", 'Images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav');
})
.then(function() {
    return myText("My name is Eve. What is your name?", 'Images/mynameiseve.wav?.wav?.wav');
})
.then(function() {
    return playAlert("Can you hear me?", 'Images/canyouhearme.wav?.wav');
});




</script>

<video controls id="video"  width="1300px" height="auto" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="images/thirdeve.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `script` tag is executed before the page in rendered in the browser and the alert stops the page from rendering until you click ok. Try adding the `script` tag after right before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript calls an alert, the alert will be the first thing to happen. nothing else will happen till the alert has been cleared.

Comment: Could I delay that series of alerts?

Comment: Even if you delay the alerts the page execution stops and waits for approval to continue.